# Compiling GTK-app in c with cygwin: invalid argument

Tags: c, cygwin, gtk3, gtkmm

I thought everything was ok since I installed

```
 MinGW
 gtk3
 gtkmm
 cygWin
```

And I have no problem to compile ordinary simple files. Neither do I have problem with commands such as

```
 $ pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0
```

it outputs

```
 -mms-bitfields -IC:/gtkmm/include/gtk-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gtk-2.0/include 
 - IC:/gtkmm/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/gtkmm/include/cairo -IC:/gtkmm/include/gdk-pixbuf 
 -2.0 - IC:/gtkmm/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/gtkmm/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/glib
 -2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/freetype2 
 -IC:/gtkmm/include/libpng14  -LC:/gtkmm/lib -Lc:/devel/dist/win32/libpng-1.4.3-1/lib 
 -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -  latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 
 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpng14 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule
 -2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

But when I try to compile a simple gtk-app from a tutorial with

```
 $ gcc c_gui.c -o c_gui `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

I get an error from the cygwin terminalwindow:

```
 :gcc.exe: error:  -LC:/gtkmm/lib: Invalid argument
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: You've passed an invalid command line argument to `gcc` perhaps? Did you look at Google's results - http://google.com/search?q=%22Invalid%20argument%22%20gcc

Answer (score 1):

Something seems to be wrong with your pkgconfig. It shouldn't be returning DOS style paths. If I run your exact command above, I get:

`-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng15 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz  -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lXinerama -lXi -lXrandr -lXcursor -lXcomposite -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lcairo -lpixman-1 -lGL -lpthread -lxcb-shm -lxcb-render -lXrender -lXext -lXdamage -lX11-xcb -lxcb-glx -lXfixes -lX11 -lxcb -lXau -lXdmcp -lharfbuzz -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lgmodule-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lffi -lglib-2.0 -lintl -liconv -lpcre -lexpat -lfreetype -lbz2 -lpng15 -lm -lz`

I suspect it's because you're trying to mix MinGW and Cygwin. They don't always work well together.

My /usr/lib/pkgconfig/gtk+-2.0.pc looks like this:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=/usr
libdir=/usr/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include
target=x11

gtk_binary_version=2.10.0
gtk_host=x86_64-unknown-cygwin

Name: GTK+
Description: GTK+ Graphical UI Library (${target} target)
Version: 2.24.23
Requires: gdk-${target}-2.0 atk cairo gdk-pixbuf-2.0 gio-2.0 pangoft2
Libs: -L${libdir} -lgtk-${target}-2.0 
Cflags: -I${includedir}/gtk-2.0
```

which looks reasonable to me.